# React Native TextInput Error: perform input operation requires a valid sessionID

Tags: react-native, expo

I have a React Native project using the Expo managed workflow with Prebuild.

I'm simply rendering a TextInput component and I am receiving this error:

> [RemoteTextInput] -[RTIInputSystemClient
> remoteTextInputSessionWithID:performInputOperation:]  perform input
> operation requires a valid sessionID

My state cannot update it's value due to this error. I am lost as to what this means.

### package.json

```
"expo": "~49.0.15",
"react": "18.2.0",
"react-native": "0.72.6",
```

After entering text into the TextInput:

> [CoreGraphics] Error: this application, or a library it uses, has
> passed an invalid numeric value (NaN, or not-a-number) to CoreGraphics
> API and this value is being ignored. Please fix this problem.
> [CoreGraphics] If you want to see the backtrace, please set
> CG_NUMERICS_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

```
<TextInput
  style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: lightGray }]}
  autoCapitalize="none"
  autoComplete="email"
  keyboardType="email-address"
  placeholder="Email"
  onChangeText={(text) => setEmail(text)}
  value={email}
/>
<TextInput
  style={[styles.input, { backgroundColor: lightGray }]}
  autoCapitalize="none"
  placeholder="Password"
  secureTextEntry={true}
  onChangeText={(text) => setPassword(text)}
  value={password}
/>
```

### UPDATE

I tried this on a fresh `npx create-expo-app` ran `npx expo prebuild` then `npx expo run:ios` and got the same result.

Comment: if you are adding an id prop to the textinput, try removing it

Comment: @FaysalB No refs or id props being used. Will add render props in the Q.

Comment: bare with me, are you importing the textinput from react native (please make sure you are), also would be nice to delete the node_modules, reinstall and rerun with --clear to clean cache

Comment: @FaysalB Yes, I'm importing from "react-native". Will delete node_modules and reinstall and revert back shortly.

Comment: @FaysalB I've deleted node_modules and reinstalled "npm install --clear" same problem

Comment: I'm surprised , sorry couldnt help

Comment: @n8o no - no idea what it is.

Comment: @DavidHenry Is everything okay to run the app?

Comment: @n8o it appears not to effect the app.